# Issue using pyserial on Rpi with python3.7

Tags: python-3

I don't know what when wrong but somehow I can't use the `serial` module from `pyserial`.

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/test $ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Apr 28 2020, 16:06:28)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
>>>
```

but according to `pip list` it is installed

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/test $ pip3 list
Package           Version
----------------- -----------
...
pyserial          3.4
...
```

I installed python3.7 and created a `python` alias for it, in case that matters.
Another funny thing is that it seems like I cannot uninstall it

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/test $ sudo pip3 uninstall pyserial
Not uninstalling pyserial at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'pyserial'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Someone has an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Python modules for every version of Python you want to use.

The correct way to install pyserial is from the repositories.

```
sudo apt install python-serial # Python 2
sudo apt install python3-serial # Python 3
```

If you are using pip (why?) try using pip3 to install pyserial.

Comment: I solved it using `pip3.7` instead of just `pip3`