# Unable to import pyserial or serial in python 3.4.2

Tags: pi-3b+, serial, python-3

I am not able to import pyserial or serial module in a python script. Package is properly installed (I think) using the following commands:

1. sudo apt-get install python3-serial
2. pip3 install pyserial --> shows up as version 3.5 installed in dist-packages (by debian)

Does anybody know what could be causing this issue and how I can solve it? Why is python 3.4 not able to find the package even though pip3 is listing it as installed?

I have all tried sudo apt-get remove python3-serial and then reinstalling but same result...

This is what my terminal shows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-serial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-serial is already the newest version (3.4-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install pyserial
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (3.5)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 21 2015, 00:53:08) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'serial'
>>>
```

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I already checked similar posts but could not find a solution:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111870/issue-using-pyserial-on-rpi-with-python3-7

Comment: According to the Python site 3.4 is end of life and Jessie is obsolete. Upgrade!

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple versions of python installed?  Perhaps the pyserial you installed is in a different python.   Try python -m pip install pyserial

Comment: Did you play around with different python versions and their alias? Seems like you've installed 2 seperate pyserial packages. Either you install it through your package manager or you install it through pip. Not both. If you don't want to install it for your system python but an other version you need to use pip. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Comment: And this is probably more suited for stackoverflow or unix.stackexchange.